# Select column range minus 2 cells in the middle, Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How would I select column range while ignoring 2 cells in the range with a formula?
like in the example:

```
    A   B
1   1   2
2   2   4
3       
4       
5   3   6
6   4
```

Need to put this in B6: `=FORECAST(4,B1:B2(B5),A1:A2(A5))`

Comment: @MátéJuhász even the question is so basic and looks like a joke - it still might be real question by the person that does not really know what a computer is, and in such case your comment is harmful - person will not get real knowledge, but false information instead...

Comment: ok I suggest such question should be deleted, makes no sence

Comment: If your question meant "how can I write ONE reference in a formula for non-contiguous range" then short answer: you can't. If you explain your situation a bit better, we may suggest you workaround

Comment: @MátéJuhász Still not clear for my why you can't when I can - and actually in formula you can do it same way with ctrl+ mouse select ranges, I just opened excel and tried - it works for me on excel 2010, I can add non-contiguous range easy exactly as I wrote in my bad answer.(by the way I tested - numbers from skipped cells are not added) I created formula for SUM

Comment: as well @MátéJuhász is fine with me when the questions are very basic and look like jokes - I can still answer, everybody learns at some point, but if you have rep of 10000+ please don't give wrong answers, if you don't know - just don't answer

Comment: here is my test formula: =SUM(A1:A2,A5:A7) this skips a3,4 ; but you can really create those ranges with mouse as I wrote in my "bad" and down voted answer.

Comment: @user733051 please edit your question instead of answering in comment,  Please include some sample data, the exact formula you've used and also the clear description of the issue.

Comment: @Drako: you can use CTRL to select multiple ranges, but those are considered to be diferent parameters by Excel. In some functions it works as designed to work with multiple ranges (SUM, AVERAGE, MIN, COUNT...) but several other functions will just give you an error message (IF, COUNTIF, VLOOKUP, ..)

Comment: @MátéJuhász even now if we go back to question itself - nothing is said about formula, there are no details; so as question requires - my answer fits 100%, when the question will be updated I will be looking for different answers. Honestly - I'm programmer - I don't use excel, I don't solve programmatic issues in excel, even if I have to - I write program in python with openpyxl lib to deal with my excel and everything always works as needed for me :) so you might be right about some specific cases, where it does not work - but as pointed earlier - that was not asked.

Comment: @Drako There is no shame in not knowing the answer, you do not have to always be right

Comment: ??? @user733051 but the answer was right for the given question - so its not shame to not know how to ask; but if you want others to help you - that's what you have to learn; was sincerely unpleasant to work on this question

Comment: no matter of that I will provide answer so you can learn at least excel, because for me it works in excel 2010, and I still can't understand how it does not for you.

Comment: @MátéJuhász now the answer is improved - as well might be useful for you too - from your comment is clear that you might benefit from learning this as well, so next time don't write that simple basic excel task is not possible to do - Microsft might bring you to court :) for anti-advertising of their product :)

Comment: Forecast just ignores empty cells, so your formula gives you the correct result (the same as there would not be empty rows), if this isn't good enough for you, then please post an example where this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As I've commented, `FORECAST` just ignores empty input, so you don't need to worry on excluding it from the input.

If you have a situation when you want to exclude input data, then you can do it with array formula.

In the below example I've just added a helper column to mark which data need to be included, however you can also write other criteria.

The formula in B6:
`=FORECAST(A6,IF(A1:A5<>100,B1:B5,""),IF(A1:A5<>100,A1:A5,""))`
Again, this is an array formula, so you need to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after inserting it.

[image]

Comment: hope this works if new info from author - can try other things too, deleted my answer, makes no sense keeping it.